# Rails Engine not routing in webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, rails-engines

I am trying to mount a rails engine [piggybak_paypal](https://github.com/CocoHot/piggybak_paypal/tree/StrongParam).
Inside my application's config/routes.rb file I add

```
mount PiggybakPaypal::Engine => '/paypal', :as => 'piggybak_paypal'
```

and the engines route is like this

```
PiggybakPaypal::Engine.routes.draw do
  get "/express" => "paypal#express", :as => :paypal_express
  get "/process" => "paypal#process_express", :as => :paypal_process
end
```

When I try `rake routes` the route of the engine is showing correctly

```
Routes for PiggybakPaypal::Engine:
paypal_express GET /express(.:format) piggybak_paypal/paypal#express
paypal_process GET /process(.:format) piggybak_paypal/paypal#process_express
```

but when I open my website and use `/express` the server cannot find the route

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/express"):
```

I've look around but I can't find a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

okay I just figure out why the routing is not working and I can't believe I spend hours on this and didn't found out why.

All I did is change the route from

`mount PiggybakPaypal::Engine => '/paypal', :as => 'piggybak_paypal'`

to

`mount PiggybakPaypal::Engine => '/', :as => 'piggybak_paypal'`

then `/express` works.